# flutter web app on app engine 404 on flutter.js

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, flutter-web, gcloud

I followed instruction from [How to deploy Flutter WebApp using Google AppEngine](https://teresa-wu.medium.com/host-flutter-webapp-with-google-appengine-bc3de7e56ba2) that consists of mainly.

1. gcloud app create
2. Creating basic app from any tool, I chose Android studio and used following values
   [image: option chosen]
3. creating app.yaml with following

   runtime: python39

   api_version: 1
   threadsafe: true

   handlers:

   - url: /
     static_files: web/index.html
     upload: web/index.html
   - url: /(.*)
     static_files: web/\1
     upload: web/(.*)
4. then executing *flutter build web*
5. this complained about *api_version* and *threadsafe* so i removed both from the app.yaml file , leaving file like

> runtime: python39
>
> handlers:
>
> - url: /
>   static_files: web/index.html
>   upload: web/index.html
> - url: /(.*)
>   static_files: web/\1
>   upload: web/(.*)

6. then flutter build web works and shows following output

> File upload done. Updating service [default]...done. Setting traffic
> split for service [default]...done. Deployed service [default] to
> [https://myxyzxyz.uc.r.appspot.com]
>
> You can stream logs from the command line by running:   $ gcloud app
> logs tail -s default

7. Below is the location of the index.html and flutter.js

> C:\projectsxyzprj>dir /s index.html flutter.js    Directory of
> C:\projectsxyzprj\build\web
>
> 01/29/2023  02:24 AM             1,862 index.html
>
> Directory of C:\projectsxyzprj\build\web
>
> 01/29/2023  02:24 AM             6,458 flutter.js
> 2 File(s)          8,320 bytes
>
> Directory of C:\projectsxyzprj\web
>
> 01/29/2023  01:54 AM             1,872 index.html
> 1 File(s)          1,872 bytes
>
> ```
>  Total Files Listed:
>            3 File(s)         10,192 bytes
> ```

8. below is the content of index.html ( auto generated by android studio)

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
>   <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">
>
>   <meta charset="UTF-8">
>   <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
>   <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">
>
>   <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
>   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
>   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
>   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="riya2">
>   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">
>
>   <!-- Favicon -->
>   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
>
>   <title>riya2</title>
>   <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
>
>   <script>
>     // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
>     var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
>   </script>
>   <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
>   <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
> </head>
> <body>
>   <script>
>     window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
>       // Download main.dart.js
>       _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
>         serviceWorker: {
>           serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
>         }
>       }).then(function(engineInitializer) {
>         return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
>       }).then(function(appRunner) {
>         return appRunner.runApp();
>       });
>     });
>   </script>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

9. When I go to https://myxyzxyz.uc.r.appspot.com in browser, the browser window shows the App title correctly but the simple counter app does not appear, in browser dev tools under network tab I see 404 for flutter.js as show below, in chrome as well as firefox.

[image]

Comment: may be https://blog.raccoons.be/hosting-flutter-web-gcp-app-engine-cloud-build ?

Comment: 1) Is ```flutter.js``` under the web folder? 2) If you use a relative path to ```flutter.js``` in your code, do you have the path as ```/flutter.js```? The path is important because your ```app.yaml``` file says - if any path is of the format ```/<filename>```, go find the file under ```/web/<filename>```

Comment: @nocommandline I have updated the question with index.html location and its contents . please suggest changes, if change goes in index.html or app.yaml

Comment: I didn't ask about ```index.html``` location. I asked how you reference ```flutter.js``` in your ```index.html``` file. Looking at the source code you pasted, change ```src="flutter.js"``` to ```src="/flutter.js"```

Comment: cp app.yaml build/web
cd build/web
gcloud app deploy

Comment: Don't understand your last comment

Comment: had to do 
flutter clean && flutter build web
per https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/104830

Comment: @nocommandline thanks, I had to copy the app.yaml to the build/web folder

Comment: @puzzled From the above comment, I believe that your issue is solved. Can you post your answer as a solution? So that, it will be useful for others who are facing same issue